# cpp-options are ignored, but why?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a typical Haskell **stack** project. I use C sources additionally to Haskell sources. And C sources use common header file like:

```cpp
// debug.h
#pragma once

#if defined(NDEBUG)
...
#else
...
#endif
```

I described additional build flag in the `package.yaml` as:

```yaml
flags:
  ndebug:
    description: "Disable C log messages"
    manual: True
    default: False
...
when:
- condition: flag(ndebug)
  cpp-options: -DNDEBUG
...
```

I tried `stack build --flag <MY-APP>:ndebug`, but I see that compiled C sources work as they had not defined `NDEBUG` macro. I tried explicit `cpp-options: -DNDEBUG` for libraries section, for executables section as well - the same. It seems that I cannot define `NDEBUG` in such way for all my C sources (ie, for `debug.h`).

**EDIT-1:**

Also I tried this:

```yaml
...
- condition: flag(ndebug)
  ghc-options:
  - -optc-DNDEBUG
...
```

without any success.

**EDIT-2:**

It seems `cxx-options:` does not work too (I found it [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/VulkanMemoryAllocator-0.10.4/src/package.yaml)).

How to achieve it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. did you find a workaround?

Comment: @user2506946 I did not. Maybe in the newest versions of stack, LTS it could work...